# How to handle dynamic changing ID's?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click this with Selenium in Python and I can't find a solution:

```
<span id="button-1299-btnIconEl" class="x-btn-icon save"></span>
```

The ID is dynamic, so it changes every time I reload the page. Also, I tried using these solutions but no luck either:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[9]/div[3]/div/div/div[12]/em/button/span[2]").click()

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id,'-btnIconEl')]").click()

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "x-btn-icon save").click()

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class="x-btn-icon save"]").click()
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What `error` are you getting ?

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: Check if the desired element is wrapped within an `iframe`

Comment: There is no Iframe

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try by using the class name :

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.x-btn-icon.save').click()`

or the title attribute :

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[title="Save"]').click()`